# passing data via segue using didSelectRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I want to pass data via segue from UITableViewController to a ViewController. The problem is that the data I want to pass the `indexPath.row` value (i.e the row selected in the UITableView).

I have declared declared a variable `var counter: Int?`in the ViewController which is known as `foodinfo`. This is my code in the UITableView:

```
var rowselected: Int?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

//what happens when row is selected
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    rowselected = indexPath.row

    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! foodinfo
        destinationVC.counter = rowselected
    }

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "dayx", sender: self)
    }
```

for some reason the `counter` in the ViewController has a value of nil. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why `prepare` is in `didSelectRowAt` overload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `prepare for segue` should not be in inside `override func tableView(` move it so its like this:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

rowselected = indexPath.row
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "dayx", sender: self)

}
```

also should be override:

```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     if segue.identifier == "dayx" {
    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! foodinfo
    destinationVC.counter = rowselected
    }
}
```

because `override func prepareForSegue` method is called after `self.performSegue`. So now you can successfully set the value `rowSelected = indexPath.row` inside `override func tableView(` and when `self.performSegue` is called it will correctly pass the data as set in the `override func prepareForSegue`

Comment: Thanks for giving it a go but counter is still coming out as nil in the foodinfo viewcontroller. its as if counter isn't being updated for some reason.

Comment: make sure you hook the segue from the vc itself not from the cell

Comment: try `destinationVC.counter = self.rowselected` if you're still using that.

Comment: If I segue from the vc itself it produces a SIGBRT error, whereas if i segue from the cell it seem to get in to the foodinfo but produce a nil for the counter.

Comment: @PeterRuppert it produces counter = nil.

Comment: strange, what if you declare `var counter = Int()` rather than an optional

Comment: @PeterRuppert `var counter = Int()` with `var rowselected = Int()` worked...kind of. No matter what row is pressed it initially makes the `counter` = 0. Then it will make the counter the previous row number selected when you try it again.

Comment: @pete800 Okay I think we will need to see more about both view controllers, maybe show the full code for both of them. + I assume the segue is connected on the storyboard from the first ViewController to the second as a Push segue?

Comment: @PeterRuppert cheers for helping. set it up as a new question because its a new thing really. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54963326/pushing-data-between-uitableview-and-uiviewcontroller-via-segue-issue

Answer (score 0):

`prepareForSegue` should be outside the `didSelectRowAt` and no need to declare the var you can make use of `sender`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {  
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "dayx", sender:indexPath.row)
}      
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! foodinfo
    destinationVC.counter = sender as! Int
}
```